# How to minify Symfony / Twig generated HTML code to satisfy Google PageSpeed Insight?

Tags: html, symfony, twig, minify

When testing my `Symfony 2.8` based webpage with Google PageSpeed Insights I am getting warned, that the HTML code is not minified.

This is true, while `Assetic` takes care of minifying all `CSS` files and `JS` scripts, the HTML code itself is quite dirty.

Google recommends to use [HTML Minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier), but since this a JavaScript tools it cannot be used as `Twig` extension, filter, etc., can it?

The `Twig` docu of the `spaceless` tag makes clear, that this tag is not meant to minify HTML and furthmore:

> If you want to create a tag that actually removes all extra whitespace
>   in an HTML string, be warned that this is not as easy as it seems to
>   be (think of textarea or pre tags for instance). Using a third-party
>   library like **Tidy** is probably a better idea.

But again I don't see how `Tidy` could be integrated into the `Twig` templates, etc.

So, what is the best way, to create minified HTML output with `Symfony` and `Twig`?

Comment: Looks like someone made a package to do this via twig, using htmlcompress https://packagist.org/packages/nochso/html-compress-twig

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question and there isn't a flagship bundle but after a quick search, you have two bundle which could help you:

### [SemaMinifierBundle](https://github.com/sergeysemko/SemaMinifierBundle)

This bundle allows you to minify in one config value all your responses (automatically on KernelResponse event) or, on demand, with a twig extension.

But this bundle is pretty old (3 years) and is not ready for Symfony3.

### [HtmlCompressorBundle](https://github.com/vihuvac/htmlcompressor-bundle)

This bundle is a bit more recent and use the htmlcompressor library.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this several years later, i created a Subscriber on `kernel.response` event.

```
# src/Event/MinificationSubscriber.php
        
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class MinificationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => ['onKernelResponse', -256]
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelResponse($event)
    {
        if (
            $event->getRequestType() != HttpKernelInterface::MAIN_REQUEST
            || $event->getRequest()->get('_route') === 'admin' // don't apply on admin pages
        ) {
            return;
        }
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $buffer = $response->getContent();

        $replace = [
            '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
            "/<\?php/" => '<?php ',
            "/\n([\S])/" => '$1',
            "/\r/" => '',
            "/\n/" => '',
            "/\t/" => '',
            '/ +/' => ' ',
        ];

        if (false !== strpos($buffer, '<pre>')) {
            $replace = [
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/" => '<?php ',
                "/\r/" => '',
                "/>\n</" => '><',
                "/>\s+\n</" => '><',
                "/>\n\s+</" => '><',
            ];
        }

        $buffer = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $buffer);

        $response->setContent($buffer);
    }
}
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678522/how-can-i-minify-html-with-twig), [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184718/using-gzip-compression-in-symfony-2-without-mod-deflate) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nasrulhazim/740bdf1175c0ad85be1864c27304aa61).